# Explore videos with youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

Can i with youtube api explore videos without added search keyword e.g. popular videos per country,new videos,last comments videos or something like that where i can get videos without added search keyword ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve and show what you have tried already?

Comment: Does youtube api offer some list of videos e.g. popular videos, or new videos ... what we can explore without use search keywords ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the [Video Feeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds?hl=en) developer guide to search for most popular videos and other feeds. You can also limit it to a certain user, country, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In v3, you can use `chart=mostPopular` option of `youtube.search.list`.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-retrieve-most-popular-videos

If you want to get TOP 10 videos in Geographic areas, 7DayTotals, 30DayTotals, ..., you can use dimensions of YouTube Analytics API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims